# find in how many combinations an object appears

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of objects. The set can be of size n. Finding the number of ways I can take m objects from this set is easy: nCm. But what I don't understand is how to calculate in how many combinations a single object appear. For example, from the set {a, b, c, d, e} can be formed 10 combinations consisting from 2 letters (ab, ac, ad ...), from which letter a appears in 4 combinations. This set can also be formed in 10 combinations consisting from 3 letters (abc, abd, abe...), from which letter a appears 6 times.

Also for the set {a, b, c, d, e,f} when choosing from 6C3 combinations (abc, abd, abe...), the answer is 10.

So my question is - how to find the number of combinations consisting of a object from nCm combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For collections of $m$ objects, that include the object $A$, we need to pick $m-1$ objects from the remaining $n-1$ to keep $A$ company.

Comment: This is not correct for the set abcdef when choosing from 6C3 combinations, the answer is 10 not 5.

Comment: Note that that my answer (and the others) say that the number is $\binom{5}{2}$, which **is** $10$.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I guess I misunderstood your answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You first choose that single object then you choose $m-1$ other objects with $C(n-1,m-1)$ different ways. Check that in your examples $n=5$ and the number of appearings are $C(4,1) , C(4,2)$

Answer (score 0):

if you have $n$ elements and want to see how many combinations of k elements have the element $x$. Check that if you take any such combination you are left with a combination of $k-1$ elements taken from the set of $n-1$ elements that are not $x$. Therefore the answer is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$, because if you fix an object you have to choose $m-1$ objects between $n-1$ .